# Populate TreeView with Distinct Child and Sub-Child Nodes from XML File

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2008, treeview

How to populate distinct child and sub child nodes in tree view from xml file ?

Comment: I've tried this:                                      `XPathDocument mySourceFile = new XPathDocument(lSourceFile); XPathNavigator myNavigator = mySourceFile.CreateNavigator(); XPathExpression myExpression;
myExpression = myNavigator.Compile("/catalog/book/author"); XPathNodeIterator myIterator = myNavigator.Select(myExpression); while (myIterator.MoveNext()) {
          XPathNavigator myNavigator2 = myIterator.Current.Clone();
          AuthorGroupNode.Nodes.Add(myNavigator2.Value);    
          }`

Comment: But, it retrieves duplicate values too.